# Bootstrap columns vertically stacking when they shouldn't be

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying to learn the Bootstrap grid system. I have the following html code that attempts to simply make a row with three columns:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          left column 
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          middle column
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          right column
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I believe this should just create three columns that align horizontally (fill up the same row), however, in Chrome, they stack vertically. Anyone know why?

[image: Chrome render]

Comment: Can you check if the bootstrap lib was imported in the page?

Comment: This code works fine with the bootstrap included properly!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a silly reply but have you checked that you have the css file correctly coming through?

row is automatically flex and col-4 is correct for 3 wide.

I cannot help but think the css file is in place.

Open up inspect element on the row element and you should see css like:

display:flex;

Comment: I changed the display property in my css file to display: flex for div elements. It improved in that all columns are on the same row, however, the columns are now all squeezed to the left side of the screen as far as they can be without overlapping. Is there a different issue, potentially?

Comment: hey @CharlieRettig, it looks like your issue is you aren't pulling through the bootstrap css or scss.

You would add on a class to the row of "justify-content-between" which would space them across the row. Or you could use "justify-content-around".

If the bootstrap css is correctly linked to your site such as what bootstrap have as their cdn link, then adding that class should work. The fact you have had to add on display:flex; yourself leads me to think it isnt.